# Cross Browser Issue - Firefox & Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, browser, rendering

I have a website

But when I view it from Chrome and Firefox, both look different. Can someone help me , why it is so ?

The screenshots:

Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hON4j.png
chrome : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ATk0.jpg

Any help shall be appreciated

Comment: We need more information dude. HTML, CSS, JS please.

Comment: Could be a million of things. Post some HTML and make sure your markup is valid http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Yes, i know it could be million of things, but i cant figure it out either..here is the link to the css file: abhiyanthriki.com/css/styles.css                                                                                                          Dont think its an issue with js or html

Comment: I think your first steps to find out why they look different, you need to use a DOM Inspector/Debugger tool like built in Chrome Dev Tools (Chrome) and Firebug - http://www.getfirebug.com (FF) to inspect the DOM and identify problems. I just can't believe you built a site like that and did not use any of those tools. PS. btw, your site looks identical to me in Chrome 20 and FF 12.

Comment: Yes. I use Chrome degugger, and is familiar with firebug too. But the problem is that in chrome, when i refresh the page, i notice slightly different styling some times. How can that be possible ?

Comment: This is what i see in chrome now, which is exactly what i want:http://i.imgur.com/xtVOb.png . but how can the styling in the page, change with time ?

Comment: @Strelok Thats what i was saying.sometimes they look identical, ( like the third screenshot that i provided ) sometimes they do not....i dont understand how that is possible

Answer (score 0):

You could start here [[http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus]](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus). Check to be sure all of the CSS3 you're using has a fall-back for each browser.

Comment: Seems like every css i used is supported by both. I use the latest versions of both Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I've just been told by AVG that your site has a virus javascript on it. May deter users!

Comment: yet my antivirus do not give me any such info. can u share a screenshot of it ?